# Can a recursive cte be used in this case?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursive-query

The following query serves its purpose well. I am learning about recursive CTE and not having an easy time doing it. I was wondering whether rCTE can be used here ? Can someone please explain why or why not? That may help me understand the concept better.

Here is the query:

```
;WITH a
AS (
    SELECT u.user_login, m.user_id, m.mail_list_id
    FROM users u
    INNER JOIN mail_list_users m ON u.user_id = m.mail_list_id

    )
SELECT a.user_login AS 'Mailing List', u1.user_login AS 'User Login'
FROM a
INNER JOIN users u1 ON a.user_id = u1.user_id
ORDER BY a.user_login
```

Comment: That is kind of difficult to say when you don't explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @JodyT Apologies. I have two tables: A) mail_list_id which has two columns, both having ids.Specifically in Manager-Employee relationship (Each Manager ID has multiple Employeed ids). Table B is the user table which has all the user details (like an employee table). The goal is to get two columns: Manager name & employee name. I basically want the mail_list_id table but instead of ids I want names. Hope this clears things.

Comment: Typically you would use a recursive CTE here if you had an unbalanced hierarchy of employees to managers.  For example, if you had an employee with a direct link to a manager combined with another employee who had a link to a team leader, who in turn had a link to the manager.  You would use the recursive CTE to work back "up the chain" until it found the actual manager, i.e. to flatten the relationships to employee/ manager.  It looks as though your data doesn't fit this, as every employee already has a direct link to their manager?

Comment: Better to put both table structures. Which field is defining the ROLE here?

Answer (score 0):

If you current query works well, why do you want to change it?

You should first consider whether you need to get data recursively. And then, if you really need a recursive process, CTE may be an option and not the other way around: meaning, you want to implement a recursive CTE whether you need data recursively or not.

Recursive CTE can use a lot of ressources and it should only be used when it is needed and it is the best option.

> A couple recursive CTEs below with a sample emplyee and manager table.

You could use a recursive CTE when you want to browse recursively through the hierachy of your managers and employees table.

If you wan't to know who is working for someone  such a God below, at any level in the hierarchy, you can use such a CTE:

```
Declare @data table(id int, name varchar(10), manager int)
insert into @data(id, name, manager) values
(0, 'God', null)
, (1, 'John', 0)
, (2, 'Bob', 1)
, (3, 'Lisa', 0)
, (4, 'Jorg', 1)
, (5, 'Mike', 3)
, (6, 'Nick', 5);

with cte(level, id) as (
    Select 0, id From @data Where manager in (Select id From @data Where name = 'God')  
    Union All
    Select level+1, d.id From @data d
    Inner Join cte c on c.id = d.manager
)
Select c.level, d.name, manager = m.name 
From cte c
Inner Join @data d on d.id = c.id
Inner Join @data m on d.manager = m.id
Order by level
```

output:

```
level name  manager
0     John  God
0     Lisa  God
1     Mike  Lisa
1     Bob   John
1     Jorg  John
2     Nick  Mike
```

Here level means that there are N manager between `name` and `God`.

If you wan't to count how many employees are working for each employee, you would use a recursive CTE like this one:

```
with cte(level, id, manager) as (
    Select 0, id, id From @data 
    Union All
    Select level+1, c.id, d.id From @data d
    Inner Join cte c on c.manager = d.manager
)
Select d.name, employees = count(*)-1
From cte c
Inner Join @data d on d.id = c.id
Group By d.name
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Output:

```
name    employees
Bob     0
God     6
John    2
Jorg    0
Lisa    2
Mike    1
Nick    0
```